# pandas lookup daily series value for half-hour dataframe index

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, lookup

I have a pandas dataframe with a half-hour timeseries index and a series of daily data that I need to match based on date for an equation.  The following code works using .get() in a loop but is slow and seems rather "unpythonic."

I've tried turning the series into a dataframe with a dummy column in order to try merge or lookup but for various reasons I can't get that to work.  There is missing data so key errors are possible with some potential methods.

Previously answered questions don't seem to apply.  Someone good with lambda functions or the .asfreq method might be able to come up with something.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Make a 2 day series
days = 2
dates = pd.date_range('20130102',periods=days)
ts_d = pd.Series(np.random.randn(days),index=dates)
ts_d

# Output

2013-01-02   -1.044139
2013-01-03   -1.061720
Freq: D, dtype: float64

# Make an overlapping 4 day dataframe with 60min index
datetimes = pd.date_range('20130101 00:00',periods=4*24, freq = '60min')
df_t = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4*24,4),index=datetimes,columns=list('ABCD'))

# Begin clunkiness
df_t['date'] = df_t.index.date
for t in df_t.index:
    d = df_t.loc[t, 'date']
    df_t.loc[t, 'E'] = ts_d.get(d)
df_t
```

Some Output:

```
                         A          B           C           D          date          E
2013-01-01 20:00:00 -0.173764   -1.440833   -0.163796    0.479593    2013-01-01  None
2013-01-01 21:00:00  1.915522    2.308827   -0.849182   -1.478981    2013-01-01  None
2013-01-01 22:00:00 -0.013391   -1.534994   -2.365495    0.747692    2013-01-01  None
2013-01-01 23:00:00  0.739665   -0.566568    0.413195    0.665017    2013-01-01  None
2013-01-02 00:00:00 -0.358202   -1.625681    0.120250   -1.122430    2013-01-02 -1.044139
2013-01-02 01:00:00  1.048837   -0.328021    0.933473   -0.234328    2013-01-02 -1.044139
2013-01-02 02:00:00  1.178195   -1.389543   -0.144850   -2.430063    2013-01-02 -1.044139
2013-01-02 03:00:00 -0.420962    0.244130    1.819005   -0.982521    2013-01-02 -1.044139
.
.
.
2013-01-02 15:00:00  1.809403   -2.505042   -0.509833   -1.238630    2013-01-02 -1.044139
2013-01-02 16:00:00  0.740123   -0.205582    0.795701    0.459017    2013-01-02 -1.044139
2013-01-02 17:00:00  1.252692    1.025432   -0.235781   -0.506460    2013-01-02 -1.044139
2013-01-02 18:00:00 -1.456726   -1.983843   -1.623061    0.629214    2013-01-02 -1.044139
2013-01-02 19:00:00  1.126687   -0.253415    0.163900    0.059876    2013-01-02 -1.044139
2013-01-02 20:00:00  0.156657    0.066207    0.103946   -0.762910    2013-01-02 -1.044139
2013-01-02 21:00:00 -1.123818    0.314226   -0.281381    0.947381    2013-01-02 -1.044139
2013-01-02 22:00:00 -0.945620    0.538180    1.403452   -0.065406    2013-01-02 -1.044139
2013-01-02 23:00:00  0.059012    2.599817   -0.623826    0.796559    2013-01-02 -1.044139
2013-01-03 00:00:00  0.859748    1.476591    0.607554   -1.575007    2013-01-03  -1.06172
2013-01-03 01:00:00  0.678326    0.084930    0.762786   -1.139595    2013-01-03  -1.06172
2013-01-03 02:00:00 -0.034952   -1.224600    0.317359   -1.620755    2013-01-03  -1.06172
2013-01-03 03:00:00 -1.208597   -1.864493   -0.883250   -0.814249    2013-01-03  -1.06172
2013-01-03 04:00:00 -0.061918    0.461941    0.163563    0.532755    2013-01-03  -1.06172
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can do this pandathonically:

first, get the date-only field:

```
df_t['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_t.index.date)
```

set as index:

```
df_t = df_t.reset_index().set_index('Date')
```

set the price:

```
df_t['E'] = ts_d
```

reset old index:

```
df_t = df_t.reset_index().set_index('index')
```

verify:

```
df_t.ix[pd.to_datetime('20130102')]
```

*edit: changed to incorporate jeff's suggestions

Comment: Thanks Much @acushner.  My test run went from 7 seconds to the blink of an eye.  Of course for the second 'set_index' I had to change from 'index' to my original name 'yr_dy_t.'  I thought about reindex but your reset set combos really made it easy.  Thanks also for the use of .to_datetime, I had been trying to remember that one.

Comment: @acushner FYI, generally better to NOT use inplace ops, then you can easily chain them, e.g. ``df.reset_index().set_index('index')``, IMHO, a nicer syntax (and ``inplace`` doesn't generally buy you anything in terms of memory or speed)

Comment: @jeff awesome, thank you so much for this tidbit. are there any cases where it does help?

Comment: on ``set_index`` it will not create a copy, but ``reset_index`` always copies. (but IMHO the syntax is just so much nicer, and virtually ALL operations are chainable like this. with ``inplace`` you CANNOT chain, which is pretty unreadable. my 2c)

Comment: totally agree about the unreadable, that's why i created a function that does it for me!

Comment: @jeff interesting discussion and  I see cush followed through with edits.  I've been  trying to figure out when I can chain and when I can't so this helps a lot.  Looking through my code I find: df_q.drop(['Unnamed: 0'], axis=1, inplace=True) so are you saying it would be better to do that with a "df_q = " instead of the inplace?  If there is no need to chain does it make a difference?

Comment: It just more 'pandonic' do NOT use inplace, IMHO, e.g. ``df_q = df_q.drop(.....)``. More readable, you KNOW that your frame is not modified in between, etc, you can simply add ``.another_operation`` if you want. I NEVER use inplace.

Comment: dammit, i really was hoping for pandathonic to catch on! thanks for the insight. some final questions: what exactly is copied? just the dataframe object itself? would the data ever be copied?

Comment: @acushner you get my vote for "pandathonically!" Good question too.  I'm not even smart enough to ask it.

Answer (score 0):

You can at least save yourself some by grouping after your `df_t` has been created:

```
df_t.loc[:, 'E'] = None
for k, group in pd.groupby(df_t, df_t.index.date):
    df_t.E[group.index] = ts_d.get(k)
```

Since `ts_d` is relatively short and hence the number of groups expected to be quite small, I would guess this to be rather efficient.